# Gnuplot command to matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, gnuplot

I'm editing some old software that runs on Fortran and uses gnuplot. I'm trying to port some parts over to python and I'm a bit confused.

I have a matrix file of Hurricane data and it plots with the command:

```
plot 'file.txt' matrix with image 1:999:1:480 w l t       ""
```

I don't fully understand the gnuplot command so when I use the plot function with matplotlib I get something totally different.

Anyone have an idea how I can plot this the same way in python?

Comment: This command, as it is doesn't work: You have specified two plotting styles `with image` and `w l` (which means `with lines`). Also, you are probably missing an `every` before `1:999:1:480`. Please correct the plotting command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Christoph: your probable gnuplot command line is close to:

```
plot 'file.txt' matrix with image every 1:999:1:480  t  ""
```

The `plot` specifications `with image` and `with line` are in conflict.
*Gnuplot* is a lover of lazines. Or you hate it or you love it :-)

You can always find shortened the commands:

```
plot  ---> pl  
with  ---> w  
lines ---> l  
title ---> t  
and so on...
```

In Python you can try with something like (it remains to filter data if it misses the `every` word in your command line...)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Read in data from an ASCII data table
data = np.genfromtxt('data.txt')

ax.imshow(data, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
#ax.imshow(data, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax.set_title('My Title')
plt.show()
```

It reproduces the effect of the gnuplot example for `help image`
In `data.txt` file I put the same data of the example

```
5 4 3 1 0
2 2 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0
0 1 2 4 3
```

Comment: As a margin of the note: I try to reproduce the original behaviour of Gnuplot. Without `interpolation` the images results different. When you migrate a code for first you have to reproduce the old one.

Comment: nitpick: please don't `from pylab import *`. In this snipped you  only use `genfromtxt`, which comes from numpy.

Comment: Modified code: so it requires less...  
@Zhenya: nitpick*nitpick _right and proper_ and after you have to write  `data=np.genfromtxt('data.txt')`